# change one number to become an integer multiple of another number in R?

Tags: r, function, math, linear-algebra, algebra

I was wondering if there might be a way in R to change `n` to become an integer multiple of `m`?

For example, if `n = 73`, and `m = 8`, then I want `n` to change to `80` (Please note that `n` could change to `72` but I want `n` to be the next larger integer, e.g., 80 not 72)?

```
m = 8 
n = 73

multiple <- function(n, m){

  #  your suggested solution #

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
multiple <- function(n,m){
  ceiling(n/m) * m
}

multiple(72,8)
# [1] 72
multiple(73,8)
# [1] 80
multiple(80,8)
# [1] 80
```